# Improve the "can no longer be reproduced" close reason

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, off-topic

Not to drag the off-topic closure reasons through the mud again, but I have a couple of issues that I think could be addressed by a slight modification to this close reason. Currently it is:

> The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

**Was there ever really a problem?**

I just [voted to close this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190596/when-asking-question-words-get-cut-out) for this reason, and I hate to be pedantic about grammar, but "can no longer" implies that there *was* a problem that *could* be reproduced in the first place. In this case, I don't think there was. He complained that the words `apply to` were removed by the system, which never happened, and later talked about the text following a URL being removed, e.g.:

```
[link](http://google/ WUT)
```

Became:

```
[link](http://google/)
```

Which I presume is by design. So maybe the wording should be:

> The problem described here cannot be reproduced at this time.

Since that implies that the problem does not exist, regardless of whether it existed at some point.

**Do we really want to create a new question if a problem can still be reproduced?**

> If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

What if I come across this question that is closed, and I am encountering the same problem? The advice seems to suggest that I should open a new question, but in some cases it might make more sense to petition the existing closed question to be re-opened (assuming there is new information available about the variables required to reproduce the issue), rather than encourage the creation of a duplicate.

Perhaps this depends on whether it has been closed by the community or tagged as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Not asking anyone to do anything yet, just trying to get community consensus about whether the wording can be improved or whether you think it's just fine the way it is.

Comment: I honestly hate that entire reason, particularly the second line: *"Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete."* - That applies to pretty much *any* completed bug report question here on Meta. This off-topic reason honestly doesn't make sense at all as worded.

Comment: Agreed. Aside from that, I'm not sure that this close reason should be located under the "off-topic" category. Because it's not off-topic, they posted it on the right site.

Comment: @Cody that's an excellent point too.

Comment: related: http://xkcd.com/583/

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, that reason exists primarily for the use of those of us working for SE. Previously, we used Too Localized for this purpose.

Of course, we can and often do just *delete* ancient bug reports that can't be reproduced, so it may turn out that this isn't really necessary in the long run.

Comment: Why have both the close reason and the norepro tag?

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn Or the [status-completed] tag, for that matter.

Comment: That said, could we all at least agree that this is *yet another* valid use of TL? And that *yet again* we're misusing a different close reason just to work around the decision to remove TL in the first place?

Comment: As for deletion: it's up to you, of course. Still, as long as deleted posts are not listed and cannot be searched, deleting makes it harder for us to find references that we still vaguely remember. So, maybe another status-tag is needed instead? (Note that Oded [once explained](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DeuGM.png) *"Don't want to clutter the front page and many of these are completely irrelevant (old browsers, pages that are no longer there, code that has been completely re-written etc...). A no-repro is not really correct either."* Cluttering won't be solved with another status-tag of course.)

Comment: @Shog9 BTW, I can't see anything like "Too Localized". Can you tel me what is that?

Comment: A close reason we got rid of years ago, @iBug